# Premature end of char-class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I had the regular expression for email validating following rules

The local-part of the e-mail address may use any of these ASCII characters:

```
Uppercase and lowercase English letters (a-z, A-Z)
Digits 0 to 9
Characters ! # $ % & ' * + - / = ? ^ _ ` { | } ~
Character . (dot, period, full stop) provided that it is not the first or last character, and provided also that it does not appear two or more times consecutively.

/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/i
```

It is working in Javascript but in Ruby http://rubular.com/ it gives error "Premature end of char-class".

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Brackets are part of regex syntax. If you want to match a literal bracket (or any other special symbol, for that matter), escape with a backslash.

this should work :

```
/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/i
```

Answer (score 1):

You should escape opening square brackets as well as closings inside the symbol range:

```
#         ⇓                        ⇓
/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)…/
```

This should be:

```
/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)…/
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: how do you put those small arrows on top of your regex ?

Comment: @aelor Within [3rd keyboard level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key) or/and [Compose Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_Key).

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin should i only escape once or twice here?

`data.gsub(/(?<!\['"])test-match/m,", content_here)` or `data.gsub(/(?<!\[\'"])test-match/m,", content_here)`

Answer (score 1):

```
irb(main):016:0> /[[e]/
SyntaxError: (irb):16: premature end of char-class: /[[e]/
        from /ms/dist/ruby/PROJ/core/2.0.0-p195/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

In JavaScript regular expression engine, you don't need to escape `[` inside a character group `[]`. However, you have to use `\[` in Ruby regular expression.

```
/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/i
```